# Getting issue to convert excel to datatable dynamically

Tags: c#

I am facing a problem on builder provider. I am converting Excel into datatable in C#.
I am getting an error at the time on OLEDB connection.
I have written code in this following way:

```cs
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
    openFileDialog.AddExtension = true;
    openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        foreach (string fileName1 in openFileDialog.FileNames)
        {
          //  Process.Start(fileName1);
            var File1 = fileName1;
            var query = "SELECT * from [Sheet1$]";
            using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection { ConnectionString = ConnectionString(File1, "Yes") })
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand { CommandText = query, Connection = cn })
                {
                    cn.Open();

                    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dt.Load(dr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public string ConnectionString(string FileName, string Header)
{
    OleDbConnectionStringBuilder Builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
    if (Path.GetExtension(FileName).ToUpper() == ".XLSX")
    {
        // Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
        Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
        Builder.Add("Extended Properties", string.Format("Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR={0};", Header));
    }
    else
    {
        Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
        Builder.Add("Extended Properties", string.Format("Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR={0};", Header));
    }

    Builder.DataSource = FileName;

    return Builder.ConnectionString;
}
```

Please give me the solution for proper Microsoft Builder Provider

Comment: `an error at the time on OLEDB connection` - and what that error would be?

Comment: You could also have a look at EPPlus: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/ This is a comfortable alternative for OLEDB-connections.

Answer (score 0):

I was checked your code, Your code is good. Even i tired with sample application. It's fine, I can able access the excel sheet data. have look below screen shot,

[image: Sample Code Screen Shot]

Here is my observation:

1. Could you please open Visual Studio in Admin, Then try
2. Check you sheet permission, Properties [Read only].
3. Have look on below suggestion from MSDB.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I followed your suggestions regarding Visual studio admin mode and sheet permission but still I am getting and issue on connection open error is like An unhandled exception type Syste.Data.OleDb.OleDbexception

Comment: Can you please share exact exception while connection

Comment: `An unhandled exception type "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbexception" occurred in System.Data.dll –` . This is very high information about exception Could you share struck trace of exception

Comment: Here is my code: [link](https://github.com/kosurucs/CodeChallengs/tree/StackFlow/FileReader) It's will help you,Seems to be issue with your `Provider:Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`

Comment: Thank you so much to share your code but I compare my code with your code it is same but when I debugging your code then it is moving in catch block when debug mode coming on cn.open();